# Analytics of application page in Google Play

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play

I have problem with analytics of my application page in Google Play. I have application, that have about 1000-2000 installs per day. I want to track views count of my application page and conversion to installs. Also, I want to know more about trafic sources. I linked my Google Play console and Google Analytics, but not integrated analytics into app (as I understand, it not required).

Now I see in analytics only 10-20 views of application page, but it's wrong (as I wrote, I have 1000-2000 installs every day).

What I'm doing wrong? Or may be Google Analytics for Google Play have any restrictions?